# Accessing real time Vive controller position data in Aframe

Tags: aframe

Description:

I have been searching for a while now through the various documentations, but I have yet to find if there is a way to obtain the real time position information for the controllers in the VR environment when using Aframe. Once the controllers are loaded and in the scene I have tried to obtain position data from

controller_left.getAttribute('position')

as well as

controller_left.object3D.position

However both always say that the controllers are at (0,0,0) even when I move them. It would seem the components I am using know where the controllers are so that sphere-collider and things like that work, however I would like to get the real time position data myself to see where the controllers are in the VR environment.

My question is more specifically regarding the Vive controllers but any insight on obtaining the position information of controllers from Aframe would be appreciated.

```
A-Frame Version: 0.7.0
Platform / Device: Firefox / Vive
Reproducible Code Snippet or URL:
```

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/jolly-nurse?path=views/index.html:18:49

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/wmurphyrd/aframe-super-hands-component#progressive-controls-component) super hands creates the controllers inside the entity consisting of the `progressive-controls`attribute. So instead of:

```
<a-entity id="con_left" super-hands></a-entity>
<a-entity id="con_right" super-hands></a-entity>
```

You should be doing:

```
<a-entity progressive-controls>
 <a-camera></a-camera>
 <a-entity class="right-controller"></a-entity>
 <a-entity class="left-controller"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

like in the github [example](https://github.com/wmurphyrd/aframe-super-hands-component#installation) :)